# Python - How to write only 'if' in one line?

Tags: python, if-statement

When I write the following it gives me an error, but I want to write it like this (in one line) how to solve it.

This works

```
if c:
    for y in r: img += '   '
```

But this doesn't

```
if c: for y in r: img += '   '
```

It returns SyntaxError

```
File "<string>", line 12
if c: for y in r: img += '   '
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Impossible, you can never do that. Just use proper formatting and separate on 3 lines, it's more readable.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: only 1 statement can be in 1 line

Comment: Doing this does not shorten runtime.

Comment: @Prometheus okay, but it works with for loop though.

Comment: @BuddyBob yeah i know that, actually I used to write code like this in other languages.

Comment: Why? The last time I checked newlines were still free of charge.

Comment: Python explicitly prohibits this (compound statements must have new line preceding them). One liner after `if` and stuff must be a simple statement. Think about the following case `if c: for y in r: img += '   ' <PHYSICAL NEWLINE> else: pass` would cause ambiguity with Python's for-else syntax. See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#compound-statements).
`

Comment: @wim hilarious!

Comment: Why do you want to make the code that much harder to read?

Comment: @pavel it's my habit, i always write if in one line incase it has one line in body.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your goal is to find the correct syntax for reaching your result in one line, it is:

```
img += ''.join(['    ' for y in r]) if c else ''
```

Comment: I was going to suggest `for y in ([] if c else r): img += '   '`.

Comment: I wonder why some humans don't understand human language. Thanks @Kraigolas for the answer.

Comment: @DanD. thanks man, your code is smaller, I'm using it!

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot do that. See that [python grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html#full-grammar-specification) for `if` statement.

```
if_stmt:
    | 'if' named_expression ':' block elif_stmt
```

This means that the `if` statemtent should start with keyword `if` followed by a `named_expression ':'` and block.

If you look at the `block` rule it's defined as,

```
block:
    | NEWLINE INDENT statements DEDENT 
    | simple_stmt
```